# How to integrate ReactJS code with a new React Native project?

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, web, react-native

I'm planning to build an android app (for my website) in React Native. And I want to know if there is a way to directly reuse components from the web version of my product which is completely built using ReactJS.

Answer (score 0):

My team recently did it. I can say it was pretty easy since we only had to change our `render` methods and the rest of our code (redux etc...) just worked.

But you can't get it to seamlessly work. Your `div` will have to change to a `View` which is styled in the code and not in `CSS`.

So you will have to do some work for your rendering, but you get to keep your components and your non-react code that doesn't interact directly with `DOM`.

Comment: What about directly embedding the HTML+JS generated from React JS into the React Native app using webview?

Comment: In that case, why would you need `React Native`? Sounds like you are going for a solution more similar to `Cordova` or `PhoneGap`

Comment: I've already tried React JS + Cordova, but some parts of the UI felt laggy especially Android Drawer and switching between tabs. So, to get a more fluid UX, I was thinking of building core parts like Drawer & Tabs in React Native and directly embed/reuse my React JS web pages for content.

Comment: Ok, so what is your question then? Obviously you can set up a view and set it to a url that serves your content

Comment: Yes, no further questions. Thanks for your help!